# How to detect other user is disconnected on sinch video call

Tags: video, call, sinch

Now I am making the video call app using sinch, but I have one problem.
If receiver click end call button, I can process it on caller side.

But assume if the receiver's network is disconnected suddenly, how to detect it on caller side.

If anyone have previous experience about it, please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: Please post code you've been working with.

Comment: There is no way for that, if the users come back it will reconnect automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for that, if the users come back it will reconnect automatically.

Its a feature that may come, but not for now

Comment: Thanks cjensen.  so sinch can not detect receiver disconnect event? can you please check my second question?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/TheCaffeineDev/Video-Call-implementation-Using-Sinch-SDK
This is the reference source code, when the receiver disconnected suddenly, the caller is still in the calling status instead of ending call and go back to the previous screen.
I want to go back previous screen when the receiver is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

My way is working fine and you can refer:
When call is established, one side created a call history record on server side contains 2 fields lastTimeCallerUpdate and lastTimeCalleeUpdate. Every minute, each side will update its current time, and check the difference of 2 fields, if variance is greater than MAX duration it will automatically call endCal();